# How to get ContextPath in struts2 action?

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 in my project. Have to generate image in my action of JSP and store it in  war file path. For this i have to get the Contextpath in Struts2. So how to get the War file path to store image/file in specified folder under WAR file?

Can anyone help me to find the Contextpath in struts2. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following code...

```
public class Page1 extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
  public HttpServletRequest request;

  @Override
  public String execute() {
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    System.out.println("Context Path " + contextPath);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  @Override
  public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!. It helped me a lot to find the solution.

Comment: how to get the list of classes of a particular java package from struts2action? I am trying using getContextPath() but getting exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
String path = request.getRealPath("/");
```

this code will work

Comment: getRealPath() on HttpServletRequest is now deprecated. Use request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") instead.